# Crashes in beginning android app

Tags: android-studio

i'm a beginner in android developing and i have the following errors on emulator i tried to find the solution by search but that was hard to find so if anyone can resove but need more details tell me

```html
 --------- beginning of crash
07-26 19:26:25.280 2672-2672/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: meddevelopers.labresultsworldwide, PID: 2672
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{meddevelopers.labresultsworldwide/meddevelopers.labresultsworldwide.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:553)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:516)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:464)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at meddevelopers.labresultsworldwide.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

i tried to do some edits to my manifest file but all were useless so i copied it to you

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="meddevelopers.labresultsworldwide">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".abbreviations" />
        <activity android:name=".hematology" />
        <activity android:name=".RBC" />
        <activity android:name=".wbc" />
        <activity android:name=".hgb" />
        <activity android:name=".hct" />
        <activity android:name=".mch" />
        <activity android:name=".mcv" />
        <activity android:name=".mchc" />
        <activity android:name=".rdw" />
        <activity android:name=".plt" />
        <activity android:name=".mpv" />
        <activity android:name=".neu" />
        <activity android:name=".lympho" />
        <activity android:name=".mono" />
        <activity android:name=".eos" />
        <activity android:name=".baso" />
        <activity android:name=".arterialvalues" />
        <activity android:name=".cardiacmarker" />
        <activity android:name=".ck" />
        <activity android:name=".ckmb" />
        <activity android:name=".ldh" />
        <activity android:name=".ast" />
        <activity android:name=".troponin" />
        <activity android:name=".myoglobin" />
        <activity android:name=".bodyfluids" />
        <activity android:name=".csf" />
        <activity android:name=".pf" />
        <activity android:name=".semenf" />
        <activity android:name=".coagulation" />
        <activity android:name=".endocrine" />
        <activity android:name=".hemodynamic" />
        <activity android:name=".lipid" />
        <activity android:name=".neurological" />
        <activity android:name=".urine" />
        <activity android:name=".urine24" />
        <activity android:name=".alal" />
        <activity android:name=".generalchem" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

In some searched i thought the problem was in the theme but i couldn't fix it too

```html
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">


    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

how can i solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever we are using AppCompatActivity  we have to use Theme.AppCompat or its descendant. If you want to use any other theme , just use android.app.Activity.

Comment: editing it in Mainactivity.java after the word "extend" ?

Comment: @AhmedAbdEl-Fattah Yes. If you like my answer, please upvote it.